# Getting count of DataFrame after zipWithIndex

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I append an index column to a `DataFrame` as follows:

```
  def addSequentialIndex(
    sc: SparkContext, 
    df: DataFrame, 
    id: String) : DataFrame = {
      val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
      sqlContext.createDataFrame(
        df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
            case (row: Row, i: Long) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ i.toDouble)
        },
      df.schema.add(id, "double")
      )
  }

val dfWithIndex = addSequentialIndex(sc, df, "id")
```

and I want to get the number of rows in `dfWithIndex`. (Context: I want to merge multiple `DataFrame`s and want to make sure they have the same number of rows.) Is there a way to do it without iterating through the `DataFrame` again? What's the least expensive way to accomplish this?

More info: `dfWithIndex.count()` gets me the result but since we're iterating through the `RDD` with `zipWithIndex()` I'm hoping we can save some compute.

Comment: What's the Spark version?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Ideally both 1.6 and 2.1, but I can separate code in order to optimize the latter.

Comment: If it's just a count you may try to use an accumulator and increment it as you build the index (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators)

Comment: Consider using `rank` to add an index column to you existing dataframe

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to compare number of rows, simplest would be `count()`

```
if dfWithIndex.count() == df2.count()
     <some operation>
```

But you want to find max of index,its not going to be efficient because it involves groupby operation

```
dfWithIndex.groupby().max(df1.id)
```